# Compare strings (stored in a array)

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to compare two strings (containing drive letters), that are stored in two "arrays". `ECHO` shows me a result like they would be the same. Could there be a problem with whitespace?

The part with problems:

```
set "i=0"
set "tmp1=!old[%i%]!"
echo %tmp1%

set "tmp2=!new[%i%]!"
echo %tmp2%

if "!tmp1!" == "!tmp2!" (
 echo Identical
)
```

`ECHO` shows for both variables C:

Comment: replace `echo Identical` with `echo %tmp1%,%tmp2%,!old[%i%]!,!new[%i%]!` and provide us with the output.

Comment: This returns `C:  ,C: ,C:  ,C:` (i placed it before the last if statement, because the if is not true)

Comment: so when `old` is equal to `new`, why do you expect a different result, when you assign their values to other variables? Your error is obviously in another part of your code (where you set your array-variables)

Comment: I just saw that the `old` and `tmp1` value has 2 blanks whereas the `new` and `tmp2` value has only 1 blank

Comment: yes, `echo` is troubleshooters best friend ^^

Comment: Thanks for your help! Now it works with `set tmp1=%tmp1: =%` and `set tmp2=%tmp2: =%`

Comment: That's more a working-on-symtoms than removing-the-error. You really should check the setting of your array-variables.

Comment: The whitespace comes from WMIC output ^^

Comment: @rwx: You may do that since the first assignment: `set "tmp1=!old[%i%]: =!"`